# Qt Bluetooth scanning not working

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I am implementing a Qt Bluetooth Application for android. my requirements are as follows :

1. I want to turn the Bluetooth ON
2. I need to scan for the device which Bluetooth is on for that we need to check.
3. I need to show all devices that are on in a list.

Currently, my first requirement is to make my code run. :)

I am struggling to scan for devices. Firstly it doesn't find all devices. Secondly, my code shows a blank list.
Would appreciate if you could let me know what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
Listview::Listview(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
{
    listModel = new QStringListModel(*stringList, NULL);
    stringList = new QStringList();

    BluetoothMain *btmain = BluetoothMain::getInstance();

    connect(btmain,SIGNAL(discovered(QString,QString,bool)),this,

    SLOT(addToList(QString,QString,bool)));
    btmain->startScan();

    qDebug()<<"bluetooth is scanning the list";

    // list_add->setModel(listModel);
    // list_add->show();
}

/*

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  stringList->append(QString::number(i)+"hi everyone");
}

list_add->setModel(listModel);
list_add->show();

*/



 void Listview::addToList(QString address,QString name,bool paired)
 {
    list_add->setModel(listModel);

    stringList->append(address);
    stringList->append(name);
    stringList->append("hi");

    list_add->show();
 }

 Listview::~Listview()
 {

 }
```

I searched for related questions but i didn't find proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

QtBluetooth only works on [Android starting Qt 5.3](http://qt-project.org/qt5/qt53), if you're using Qt 5.2, it won't work.

Also, did you try to compile basic Qt example?

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtbluetooth-btscanner-example.html

If this works by simply opening, compiling and deploying the .pro file from QtCreator, your program should work too!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to complete points 1, 2, 3 is provided in [1]:

1. To turn Bluetooth ON, use code from the section "**Retrieving Local Device Information**":

   ```
    //  Somewhere in the code inside custom class
    QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;
    //  Turn Bluetooth ON
    localDevice.powerOn();
   ```
2. To scan for devices, section "**Scanning for Bluetooth Devices**":

   ```
    //  Create discovery agent
     QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);

    //  Connect signal to slot. "This" pointer corresponds to your custom class
    connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)),
        this, SLOT(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)));

    // Start a discovery
    discoveryAgent->start();
   ```
3. To show all discovered devices, use the method

   ```
   void MyClass::deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device)
   {
       qDebug() << "Found new device:" << device.name() << '(' << device.address().toString() << ')';
   }
   ```

Finally, the code should not show all the devices, because generally not all devices have Bluetooth adapter ON, and not all devices are discoverable, even if their adapter is ON.
[1]: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtbluetooth-overview.html